# Reduce the height of inline li?

Tags: html, css

I am using inline unordered list for menu tab. I can see that height of li is greater than ul. I would like to set the height of li to ul. How can I do that can anyone help please.

Comment: Did you try giving the `li` elements zero padding on the top and bottom, and zero margin on the top and bottom?  What have you tried?

Comment: @Ray Toal Tes but it is not working

Answer (score 3):

```
ul, li {
    height:50px;
}
```

........

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the set the height of an `li` to the height of the parent `ul`, you would use the `inherit` feature:

```
li {
  height: inherit;
}
```

Alternatively, you can set both of them to the same number:

```
ul, li {
  height: /*insert height*/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ul { position: relative; }

li { height: 100%; }
```

Comment: Can you improve this answer, by providing some details what this does and in what browsers it works?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use inline <li>? You can always use it like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

CSS code:

```
ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  height: xxxx; //anythin you want here
}
```

The only problem with that solution is constant width of menu item. If you really need this, your solution will be inline-block CSS property.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul li {
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 90px;
}
ul {
    background: green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li><a href="">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Three</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

You can set width, height, background and many others, but element will be still inside of text flow.

Preview of this code: http://albitos.eu/~albi/stackoverflow/inline-li-height.html